# Enabling Intel Virtualization

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization

I own an Asus GL552VX. In my BIOS all virtualization technologies are in the enabled state. I was able to use software such as NoX (emulators) and Hyper-V (Not enabled now). All of a sudden (a few months back), NoX started crashing (I am not sure if it is after a major Windows update but perhaps). I am using a Windows 10 Home (Single Language - 17134.523). Now, Oracle VirtualBox says the following.
[image]

Now, my questions are,

1. Why does it show that something is not available while it was working fine?
2. How to fix the issue (No mobo changes or anything ever happened).

Thank you!

Comment: I have a few questions, and the answers to these questions, are required to answer your question.  Please provide the answers as an edit to your question.  Do you have Core Isolation enabled?  Do you have currrently have VT-x turned on?  What processor do you have percisely?  What security software do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the new feature called the Core Isolation. Once I disable this the problem got resolved.